# Cakephp collections add new element within closure function

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP `Collections` to iterate records. I want to create a new element in each called `balance_history` but I cannot seem to append it. I get no error.

```
    $journalEntries = $this->JournalEntries->find()
        ->where(['journal_id' => $journal_id])
        ->contain('Strategies.StrategiesConditions', 'JournalEntriesStrategyConditions')
        ->enableHydration(false)
        ->toList();

    $collection = new Collection($journalEntries);
    $closeDateSorted = $collection->sortBy('close_date_time', SORT_ASC);

    $balance = $journal->starting_balance;
    $closeDateSorted = $closeDateSorted->each(function ($jEntry) use (&$balance) {
        $balance += $jEntry['profit'];
        //$jEntry += [ "history_balance" => $balance ];
        $jEntry['history_balance'] = $balance;
    });
    debug($closeDateSorted->toArray());

[
    (int) 2 => [
        'id' => (int) 23,
        'journal_id' => (int) 1,
        'ticket_number' => 'testbalance2',
        'entry_date_time' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-09-03 00:08:22.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'entry_price' => null,
        'strategy_id' => null,
        'timeframe' => '',
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-08-27 20:54:54.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-08-27 20:54:54.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'strategy' => null
    ],
    (int) 0 => [
        'id' => (int) 21,
        'journal_id' => (int) 1,
        'ticket_number' => 'sdfsdfsdf 2',
        'entry_date_time' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-09-05 07:49:04.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'entry_price' => null,
        'strategy_id' => null,
        'timeframe' => '',
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-08-26 22:33:28.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-09-21 20:35:12.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        }
    ],
    (int) 4 => [
        'id' => (int) 32,
        'journal_id' => (int) 1,
        'ticket_number' => 'sdfsdf',
        'entry_date_time' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-10-19 20:28:46.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'entry_price' => null,
        'strategy_id' => null,
        'timeframe' => '',
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-09-19 20:29:33.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-09-19 20:29:33.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'strategy' => null
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'id' => (int) 22,
        'journal_id' => (int) 1,
        'ticket_number' => 'testbalance',
        'entry_date_time' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-09-03 00:08:13.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'entry_price' => null,
        'strategy_id' => null,
        'timeframe' => '',
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-08-27 20:49:41.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-08-27 20:49:41.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'strategy' => null
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'id' => (int) 31,
        'journal_id' => (int) 1,
        'ticket_number' => 'cvbcvb',
        'entry_date_time' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-09-18 21:06:12.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'entry_price' => null,
        'strategy_id' => null,
        'timeframe' => '',
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-09-19 20:09:51.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-09-19 20:09:51.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'strategy' => null
    ]
]
```

Comment: So what is the debugging result?

Comment: sorry should have added earlier

Comment: Looks like the things in your collection are arrays, which would not be passed by reference to the callback function. Any chance you can make them entities or ArrayObjects instead?

Comment: Thanks @GregSchmidt. I have removed `->enableHydration(false)` and not it works.